# Running a SWIG bound Python+C program gives a missing DLL error when running on another computer

Tags: python, c, swig

So I have compiled a small testing program that uses SWIG as a bridge between python and C. The main part of the program is the python file. The thing runs fine on my own pc, but as soon as I transfer it to another, it immediately throws a "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found." error. I tried to see if it could be a file location that was statically coded by moving it to another directory on my own pc, which still worked fine. Next I did some debugging in the SWIG python wrapper, and found out what DLL it was loading; whose file path was correct too. My other PC also had the correct path. Does anyone know something that I might have forgotten that causes this error?

Comment: Could be the DLL itself has dependencies. Check the event log and use Dependency Walker http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to find out which DLLs might be missing.

Comment: It also can help to know what C compiler you are using.

Comment: The dependency walker did the trick. I was missing the glut32.dll file :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everyone having this problem should probably check out the [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), and see what DLLs are missing. It solved my problem.